# Issue importing C# library into Python: Module Not Found

Tags: python, c#, import

I have created a C# wrapper for a library, like so:

```
namespace seedwrapper
{
    public class Find_Seed : System.Dynamic.DynamicObject
    {
        private GroupSeedFinder functions;
        public Find_Seed()
        {
            functions = new GroupSeedFinder();
        }
        public ulong find_seed(string folder)
        {
            var inputs = functions.GetInputs(folder);

            return functions.FindSeed(inputs);

        }
    }

}
```

And I'm importing this into python. I have all the .dlls loaded in, but I'm getting the following error: Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'seedwrapper' when I import the module.

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("seedwrapper")

from seedwrapper import Find_Seed
```

I have tried adding it to the sys path, I've tried looking at different directories, I've tried changing the namespace, no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Is that filename seedwrapper.cpp?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what my issue was. I was exporting in .NET 6.0, which isn't one of the export methods that work with this. I changed it to .NET common 2.0 and it imported correctly.